# installing python-software-properties on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I am trying to install python-software-properties package on an ubuntu 12.04 machine. I keep getting:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-software-properties : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
                          Depends: python-pycurl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Aptitude shows the version it is attempting to install is 0.75.10.3. I have run apt-get update, of course. I need this to add a ppa to my repo list.

Comment: You don't seem to have all your repositories updated to use Ubuntu 12.04. As you can see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-software-properties) it depends on Python >= 2.7.1 and your version is depending on < 2.7 and seems to be from Ubuntu 10.04 as you see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/python-software-properties). Please provide the output of `apt-cache show python-software-properties | grep ^Version`. And next time, ask this on AskUbuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Running the above command gives: Version: 0.75.10.3\n Version: 0.75.10

Comment: Then check your repository settings - it's broken. This does not break by itself. Run `grep -r lucid /etc/apt/sources.list*` to see what is still on Lucid. Did you upgrade from 10.04? Please tell the whole story about your repository settings/configuration.

Comment: I see a whole lot of lines with lucid. Actually, the whole sources.list file looks like it belongs to lucid. /etc/issue says: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. I know only a little about the history of the machine. I was told that it was running 12.04. I was asked to install Java7 on the machine, that's when I tried to add a PPA for which I needed python-software-properties. Is there any hope that I could clean up the mess? Thanks again for your quick response. PS: BTW I see a back up of sources.list that definitely belongs to precise pangolin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These two lines from the comments summarize your issue perfectly:

> I see a whole lot of lines with lucid. Actually, the whole sources.list file looks like it belongs to lucid.
>
> I was told that it was running 12.04.

It is in some way, but not all. If it's not too much work, I suggest to start all over in a new installation.

Alternatively,

1. [regenerate your APT sources](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) and put them in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
2. make sure only `precise` sources are listed/configured (including in the files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.
3. Run `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get update`.
4. update/upgrade all packages (e.g. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`)

However, this does not ensure all packages are in a clean state, so you might end up into trouble again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have a clear picture of what is going on. I will discuss with the team and decide which way to go. Great trouble shooting!